# Can someone explain today.getDate() > 25 ? 5 : (today.getDate() > 16 ? 25 : 15)

Tags: javascript

I need help with today.getDate string.

Can someone explain meaning of this:

```
x = today.getDate() > 25 ? 5 : (today.getDate() > 16 ? 25 : 15)
```

I understand it like this:
if today is > 25 = 5
else today is > 16 = 25
else 15

It is part of APR calculation in lease calculator.
Let say you have:

```
var price_of_product = 999;
var some_taxes = 119.88;
var total_plus_taxes = price_of_product + some_taxes;
var months = 12;
var monthly_payment = 98.24;
```

Calculator is using moment.js but it is not calulating APR with XIRR function as Excel.

Comment: You're understanding it correctly

Comment: i am not undesrtanding,where you are giving date?

Comment: date <= 16 then 15;
date > 16 && date <=25 then 25;
date > 25 then 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain meaning of this?

```
x=today.getDate()>25?5:(today.getDate()>16?25:15)
```

This is using [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator.

If `today.getDate()` is greater than 25 is equal to true, then it returns `5`, else it returns *(if `today.getDate()` is greater than 16, then it returns `25`, else it returns `15`)*... (correct)

If you're using `new Date()` to generate the today's date in `today`, calling the property `getDate` in `today`, then it would return an integer of the day number: `9` (not an string).

Comment: Because first payment after the lease contract is signed depends on the date that the contract is signed i need correct date. But it is not working as should. 
If client signed contract between 01.01-05.01.2016 then the first payment and every next payment starts on 05.next-month.2016. If it is signed between 06.01-15.06.2016  then the first payment and every next payment starts on 15.next-month.2016. If client signed contract between 16.01-31.01.2016 then the first payment and every next payment starts on 25.next-month.2016.

Comment: Don't use `Date()` to get the date (I think it returns the date from client's computer), use PHP. You can make a Ajax request to an PHP file that returns the correct and current date of know.

Comment: Read more about `Ajax` in javascript.